# Logstash isn't shipping application logs to elasticsearch

Tags: logstash

I set up logstash with elasticsearch and kibana. Everything works fine for tomcat logs and windows logs, but now I want to integrate my own application logs.

I tested my grok parser with the grokdebugger and it seems to be fine, also the configtest of logstash sends me back "ok". I also tried to write the log to a file instead of sending it to elasticsearch but this doesn't work either.

```
input {
    file {
        type => "applog"
        path => "C:/web/*.txt"
        start_position => beginning
    }
}

filter {
    if [type] =~ "applog" {
        grok{
            match => { "message" => "%{DATE_EU:event_date}\s%{TIME:event_time}\s*\[%{HOST:threadname}\]\s%{LOGLEVEL:level}\s*%{JAVACLASS:class}\s-\s*%{GREEDYDATA:derrest}" }
        }
        mutate {
            add_field => { "timestamp" => "%{event_date}\s%{event_time}" }
        }
    }                 
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch_http {
        host => "localhost"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }          
    file {
        path => "C:/web/test"
    }
}
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the log if you start Logstash with `--debug`?

Comment: He is trying to do this for the whole time, seems he doesnt find the file: ←[36m_discover_file_glob: C:/web/*.txt: glob is: [] {:level=>:debug, :file=>"/Us
ers/logstash-1.4.2/vendor/bundle/jrub
y/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.5.1/lib/filewatch/watch.rb", :line=>"117"}←[0m

Comment: I wonder if you really should use forward slashes. I suspect you should use backslash instead.

Comment: Still the same problem, in some lines of the log there is a "|" character in the "greedydata" pattern, could this be a problem?

Comment: Grok patterns don't cause whole messages to get lost. If the `_discover_file_glob` messages say `glob is: []` your problem is that Logstash doesn't find any files that match your filename patterns. Ignore everything else for now.

Comment: I fixed to problem, big mistake by myself, i was pretty sure the logs got the filetype txt but they didn't thats because they hadn't be found, thanks for your help!